# $f$ is divisible by a square of non-constant polynomial iff $f,f'$ are not relatively prime

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

> Let $R$ be a commutative ring and $f=a_0+ \cdots +a_nt^n \in R[t]$. Define $f':=a_1+2a_2t+ \cdots + na_{n-1}t^{n-1}$. Show that $f$ is divisible by a square of non-constant polynomial if and only if $f,f'$ are not relatively prime.

The forward direction is easy: suppose $g^2 | f$ and $\deg(g) \neq 0$. Then $f=g^2h$ for some $h$ and $f'=2gg'h+g^2h$. So we have $g|f'$ and $f, f'$ are not relatively prime. How should I prove the converse is also true?

Comment: The claim is false as it is stated. (See my comment under the answer.) However it is right over a field.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As $f$ and $f'$ are not relatively prime, there exists a non-constant prime polynomial $p$ such that $p \mid f$ and $p \mid f'$. Since $p \mid f$, there exists a polynomial $h$ such that $f=ph$. Thus, by product rule $f'=p'h+ph'$. Since $p \mid f'$ and $p \mid ph'$, $p \mid p'h$. By definition of the derivative, $p'$ has a lesser degree than $p$ and thus $p \nmid p'$. Since $p$ is prime and $p \mid p'h$, this means that $p \mid h$. Thus, there exists a polynomial $h_2$ such that $h=ph_2$. Since $f=ph$, $f=pph_2=p^2h_2$. Thus, $f$ is divisible by $p^2$, the square of a non-constant polynomial.

Comment: $f=2X+2$ and $f'=2$ are not relatively prime in $\mathbb Z[X]$. However, the proof works over a field.

Comment: @user26857 Yes, you're right. I assumed that by "not relatively prime," he meant they share a non-constant polynomial because otherwise, the statement would be false.